# Idea behind the definition of direct image of $\mathscr{D}$-modules

Tags: algebraic-geometry, d-modules

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a morphism of smooth algebraic varieties over $\mathbb{C}$.

Since $\mathcal{D}_{X\to Y}$ is a $(\mathcal{D}_X,f^{-1}\mathcal{D}_Y)$-bimodule, given a right $\mathcal{D}_X$-module $M$, we have a natural right $\mathcal{D}_Y$-module defined as
$$f_*(M\otimes_{\mathcal{D}_X} \mathcal{D}_{X\to Y}).$$

If I understood correctly, the idea now is to use the equivalence of categories between left and right $\mathcal{D}$-modules to obtain a direct image of *left* $\mathcal{D}$-modules. This should work in the following way:

1. We begin with a left $\mathcal{D}_X$-module $M$;
2. Then we obtain a right $\mathcal{D}_X$-module $M\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X}\omega_X$;
3. Then we do the preceding operation, resulting in the right $\mathcal{D}_Y$-module $f_*(M\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X}\omega_X \otimes_{\mathcal{D}_X}\mathcal{D}_{X\to Y})$;
4. Finally, we obtain the left $\mathcal{D}_Y$-module $\omega_Y^\vee\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_Y} f_*(M\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X}\omega_X \otimes_{\mathcal{D}_X}\mathcal{D}_{X\to Y})$.

This doesn't seems to agree with the usual definition $f_*(\mathcal{D}_{Y\leftarrow X}\otimes_{\mathcal{D}_X}M)$. What is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like an application of the projection formula to me. Let me try.

$$
\omega_Y^\vee\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_Y} f_*((M\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X}\omega_X) \otimes_{\mathcal{D}_X}\mathcal{D}_{X\to Y})
\cong \omega_Y^\vee\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_Y} f_*((\mathcal{D}_{X\to Y}\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X}\omega_X) \otimes_{\mathcal{D}_X}M)
\cong
f_{*}(f^{*}\omega_Y^\vee\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X}(\mathcal{D}_{X\to Y}\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X}\omega_X \otimes_{\mathcal{D}_X}M))
\cong
f_{*}((f^{*}\omega_Y^\vee\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X}\mathcal{D}_{X\to Y}\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X}\omega_X) \otimes_{\mathcal{D}_X}M)
\\
\cong f_{*}((f^{-1}\omega_Y^\vee\otimes_{f^{-1}\mathcal{O}_{Y}}\mathcal{O}_{X}\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X}\mathcal{D}_{X\to Y}\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X}\omega_X) \otimes_{\mathcal{D}_X}M)
\cong f_{*}((f^{-1}\omega_Y^\vee\otimes_{f^{-1}\mathcal{O}_{Y}}\mathcal{D}_{X\to Y}\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X}\omega_X) \otimes_{\mathcal{D}_X}M)
$$

Depending on what definition of $D_{Y\leftarrow X}$ you work with this could answer your question.

In my point of view $D_{Y\leftarrow X}=f^{-1}\omega_{Y}^{\vee}\otimes_{f^{-1}\mathcal{O}_{Y}}\mathcal{D}_{X\rightarrow Y}\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{X}}\omega_{X}$ and the left $D_{Y}$ module structure of the direct image of $M$ comes from the right $f^{-1}D_{Y}$-module structure of $\mathcal{D}_{X\rightarrow Y}$ which turns $D_{Y\leftarrow X}$ into a left $f^{-1}\mathcal{D}_{Y}$-module by tensoring with $f^{-1}\omega_{Y}^{\vee}$ and therefore $f_{*}(\mathcal{D}_{Y\leftarrow X}\otimes_{D_{X}}M)$ into a left $\mathcal{D}_{Y}$-module.

Comment: Hi Joo! Could you explain the second isomorphism a little further?

Comment: This is just the commutativity of the tensor product of modules over a sheaf of $\textit{commutative}$ rings. That is: I swap the factors of the tensor product and then I write down what $f^{*}\omega_{Y}^{\vee}$ means by definition.

Comment: I just realized the formula is still not in the form you wanted it. Hang on, I'll try and fix this.

Comment: It should be fixed. Is this the formula you wanted? What's your definition of $\mathcal{D}_{Y\leftarrow X}$ and in particular: How is the $\mathcal{D}_{Y}$-module-structure on $f_{*}(D_{Y\leftarrow X}\otimes_{\mathcal{D}_{X}}M)$ defined?

Comment: This is perfect @Joo! Thank you a lot :)

Comment: You are welcome :)

Comment: This looks to me like an abstract painting of René Magritte, I don't understand anything, but still think it's beautiful and want to decode the meaning hiding within.  (sorry if I am been too dramatic :p) ... any good book for absolute beginners in algebraic geometry and D-modules ?

Comment: @Petros That depends on your prerequisites. I suggest you open up a new thread on this question so that other who might be interested in it can easily find it.